# Multiple Ffmpeg instances choking up the CPU to 100%

Tags: video, cpu, ffmpeg, c#, concatenation

I have a task to record timelapse videos from multiple IP-cameras (e.g. camera1.mp4, camera2.mp4, camera#.mp4,etc.). Currently i am running separate ffmpeg.exe instances simultaneously on an MS Azure VM (C2D, 7GB RAM). Each ffmpeg.exe is responsible for concatenating newly taken image (every 1 minute) from camera with its existing .mp4 file hence creating final camera#.mp4.

Although, I have used tricks like limiting ffmpeg.exe to use 1 CPU core only among 4 available but its still choking up the CPU to 100% almost always.

Any idea to improve this situation, please suggest? 
(may be: someone has done similar thing by using single ffmpeg.exe instance, doing concatenation tasks queued up against each camera ?)

OR any other helping ideas/clues please to fix the issue.

Comment: Why is utilizing the available resources to 100 % a problem for you?

Comment: When the CPU is being used 100%, it, 1) slows down server response against video playback request, 2) does not allow me to connect to the server via RDP

Comment: That sounds like you might want to configure process priorities.

Comment: Using "-threads 1" parameter [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4565633/369383], I have already restricted CPU cores to 1. Also I have read somewhere that ffmpeg's priority can not be set. Please suggest some way if you know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're on windows; why not use the ["start" command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) with a lower than normal priority, eg `/LOW`. It will still use 100% of the CPU when it can, but only if nothing else wants it.